# How to get epoch of custom date and time in java?

Tags: java, java-time, epoch

I want an epoch of every day at 12pm. I have tried to make a function that makes a string of date time and has to convert into an epoch but this doesn't work and also it shows 12pm to 0(zero)  I don't know why

here's what I have tried but show error:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month=now.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int date=now.get(Calendar.DATE);
        String yearInString = String.valueOf(year);
        String monthInString=String.valueOf(month);
        if(monthInString.length()==1){
            monthInString="0"+monthInString;
        }
        String dateInString=String.valueOf(date);
        if(dateInString.length()==1){
            dateInString="0"+dateInString;
        }
        int hour=now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        String hourInString=String.valueOf(hour);
        int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        String minuteInString=String.valueOf(minute);
        if(minuteInString.length()==1){
            minuteInString="0"+minuteInString;
        }
        int second=now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        String secondInString=String.valueOf(second);
        String HRD=yearInString+"-"+monthInString+"-"+dateInString+" "+hourInString+":"+minuteInString+":"+secondInString;
        System.out.println(HRD);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(HRD, dtf);
        Instant instant = dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

and also tried this

```
Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(HRD);
long epoch = date1.getTime();
System.out.println(epoch);
```

but show error

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-10-06 0:29:43' could not be parsed at index 11
> at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
> at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
> at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:494)
> at customepoch.main(customepoch.java:35)

Comment: Are you trying to get epoch for a moment in time that is defined by your local time (in your zone) or by UTC time?

Comment: Yes can you please help me with that

Comment: Yes to which part of my question?

Comment: Sorry i need local time zone

Comment: Since you can use java,time, the modern Java date and time API (`DateTimeFormatter` , `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` and `ZoneOffset`), don’t also involve the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class. java.time gives you all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** From the `OffsetDateTime` at 12 pm, you can get the corresponding `Instant` using [`OffsetDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant--) and from this `Instant`, you can get the epoch milliseconds.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime todayAtNoon = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC), LocalTime.NOON, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        OffsetDateTime lastDateOfMonth = todayAtNoon.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        for (OffsetDateTime odt = todayAtNoon; !odt.isAfter(lastDateOfMonth); odt = odt.plusDays(1)) {
            System.out.println(odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1633521600000
1633608000000
1633694400000
...
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/JMHYvi)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### What went wrong in your code?

There are already two answers showing you how to obtain the numbers you want. I am not repeating that.

Rather I am posting this answer because I sensed a curiosity: Why did your code show 12 PM as 0 (zero)? Why did you get the error (exception)? This is what I am addressing here.

- First as has been said directly or indirectly you were using the `Calendar` class for obtaining the current time in your time zone. `Calendar` is poorly designed and long outdated. Don’t do that.
- Your conversion from `Calendar` to `Instant` was very, very complicated. If you had got a `Calendar` from some legacy API and wanted to convert it (which you don’t want for your current purpose), all you had needed was:

  ```
       Instant instant = now.toInstant();
  ```

  That’s right, since Java 8 `Calendar` has got a `toInstant` method for the conversion. The other old date and time classes have got similar conversion methods added.
- You tried:

  ```
       int hour=now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  ```

  `Calendar.HOUR` is for hour within AM or PM from 0 though 11. This explains why you got 0 for 12 PM. `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is for hour of day from 0 through 23. It’s just one of the many confusing points about `Calendar` and one of the many reasons why I recommend you don’t use it.
- You prepended month, day of month and minute with `0` to make sure you had got two digits. You didn’t do the same for hour and second. Since your hour was 0, it was only one digit and did not match `HH` in the format pattern, which requires two digits. This caused the exception that you reported.
- You tried this formatter for parsing:

  ```
       DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  ```

  The string you built did not include milliseconds. You should either leave out `.SSS` or you should add the fraction of second to your string.
- This seems to conflict with your intention:

  ```
       Instant instant = dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  ```

  Since you wanted the time in your local time zone, it should have been:

  ```
       Instant instant = dt.toInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your local timezone properly set for your JVM so that it is available with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Assume also you start from today (06-Oct-2021). Then your code would be:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.OCTOBER, 6, 12, 0);
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(
                start
                        .plusDays(i)
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                        .toEpochSecond()
        );
    }
}
```